# What is a good way to get historical Twitter follower numbers?

Tags: api, twitter

I need the historical numbers of followers for a set of 60 Twitter users. Unfortunately the official Twitter API only returns the most current follower count. I know that there is probably no one-size-fit all and fool-proof way to get an accurate follower growth graph for all users in my list. However, would there be a good and logical way to estimate or deduce this based on other information available through Twitter API (e.g. number of retweets, likes)?  I read somewhere that retweet rate grows proportionally with number of followers.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think any approximation would be based on some criteria that would most probably not be applicable to all users.

From my point of view, I would start recording the followers from now on in your database and build a graph starting from today and not from the past.

Answer (score 1):

There are services that allow you to buy or access historical data. But only if they have been tracking the account already. For large accounts, it is more likely, but for smaller accounts they probably haven't been tracking them.

https://twittercounter.com/pages/buy-stats/apple

I haven't used these services but I assume they are accurate.